# How to pass a string as an argument when the function has integer as parameter?

Tags: c, openssl, macros

I am trying to implement error handling for OpenSSL, to generate an error in OpenSSL I looked into a function ERR_put_error which puts the error specified in the arguments in the error queue of the thread. This function has a definition of:

```
 void ERR_put_error(int lib, int func, int reason, const char *file, int line);
```

As you can see it accepts func as an integer argument. But we call this function as :

```
ERR_put_error(ERR_LIB_SSL,
              SSL_F_SSL3_GET_RECORD,
              SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY,
              OPENSSL_FILE,
              OPENSSL_LINE);
```

SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY is defined in openssl code at include/openssl/sslerr.h and it looks like this:

`#define SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY        291`

This is because SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY is a macro which corresponds to an integer. I have created a character array containing the name of all the errors. Now as I am giving input as a string(passing the integer input to the error array and obtaining the name) that has the same name as SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY.

When I pass it to this function it throws an error as it expects an integer but argument is of type char *. So my question is why this string is not getting expanded to an integer? Also, how can I implement this by taking input as a string?

Comment: can you show the code for `SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY` macro. You said it is an integer and also a string.

Comment: If an API function expects an integer, why do you think you can pass a string? And why would you want to do this it in the first place?

Comment: "why this string is not getting expanded to an integer" How should this happen? IStrings are never "expanded" automatically. Macros are replaced by preprocessor, strings aren't.

Comment: @Gerhardh ... As I mentioned I am implementing a error handler for my application and to see that it can handle all the errors first I need to produce them...there are over 200 errors in openssl and each is defined with the macros as mentioned in the question

Comment: I do not see how this might make any sense. Maybe you could provide some code how you intent to call the function and combine with your array of strings.

Comment: Update the answer with the exact error message copied from your terminal.

Comment: *"Now as I am giving input as a string(passing the integer input to the error array and obtaining the name) that has the same name as SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY."* - Show the code

Comment: Implementing an error handler is no reason to pass strings. You can use your array of strings to create some output but then pass the real value (=integer) to openssl. If there are 200 errors defined, how would using strings reduce the effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created a character array containing the name of all the errors.

Did you mean this?

```
  char err[256] = "SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY "
                  "SSL_R_APP_DATA_IN_HANDSHAKE "
                  "SSL_R_ATTEMPT_TO_REUSE_SESSION_IN_DIFFERENT_CONTEXT"
                  "SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_0_NEEDED_IN_FIPS_MODE"
                  "SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_2_NEEDED_IN_SUITEB_MODE"
                  "SSL_R_BAD_CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC"
                  "SSL_R_BAD_CIPHER"
                  "SSL_R_BAD_DATA";
```

or this?

```
  char err[256] = {SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY,
                  SSL_R_APP_DATA_IN_HANDSHAKE,
                  SSL_R_ATTEMPT_TO_REUSE_SESSION_IN_DIFFERENT_CONTEXT,
                  SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_0_NEEDED_IN_FIPS_MODE,
                  SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_2_NEEDED_IN_SUITEB_MODE,
                  SSL_R_BAD_CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC,
                  SSL_R_BAD_CIPHER,
                  SSL_R_BAD_DATA
                  };
```

In both the case below call will not work.

```
ERR_put_error(ERR_LIB_SSL,
              SSL_F_SSL3_GET_RECORD,
              err,
              OPENSSL_FILE,
              OPENSSL_LINE);
```

since `err` is of type `char *` but function accepts `int`.

---

You can try defining as below and call the function in loop.

```
   int err[8] = {SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY,
                  SSL_R_APP_DATA_IN_HANDSHAKE,
                  SSL_R_ATTEMPT_TO_REUSE_SESSION_IN_DIFFERENT_CONTEXT,
                  SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_0_NEEDED_IN_FIPS_MODE,
                  SSL_R_AT_LEAST_TLS_1_2_NEEDED_IN_SUITEB_MODE,
                  SSL_R_BAD_CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC,
                  SSL_R_BAD_CIPHER,
                  SSL_R_BAD_DATA
                  };

    for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++) {
         ERR_put_error(ERR_LIB_SSL,
                    SSL_F_SSL3_GET_RECORD,
                    err[i],
                    OPENSSL_FILE,
                    OPENSSL_LINE);
    }
```

Comment: I was implementing it the first way char err[256] = "SSL_R_APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY "....That's what I was doing wrong..I should have created an array of macros(as you mentioned) rather than an array containing the names of the errors in string format. Thanks